# Ответ сервлета на http-запрос не html-содержимым

Tags: java, json, servlet, http, https

Здравствуйте. Хотел бы реализовать веб-сервис на технологии **Java** - *сервлеты*. Возможно ли *сервлетом* как основным моим обработчиком запросов к нему отдавать запрашивающему клиенту не **html**-страницу, а некую структуру из следующих: **xml**, **JSON**? Дело в том, что клиент, генерирующий запросы - не браузер, а какое-то приложение, работающее с **JSON**, **xml** структурами.

И еще вопрос вдогонку: возможно ли взаимодействовать с *сервлетом* посредством шифрованных протоколов (**https** и прочие)?

Comment: Так JSON или XML? Обычно это альтернативы друг-другу и сомнительно чтобы в пределах одного протокола использовалось и то и другое

Comment: Имелось в виду либо либо.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что вопрос звучит "можно ли", а не "как это сделать". Ответ: можно)

Answer (score 0):

https безусловно можно (это вопрос настроек сервера).

По поводу **не html**. IMHO можно, надо только как-то (наверняка в методах построения responce это есть) задать нужный Content-Type в заголовке http-responce.

Comment: > https безусловно можно (это вопрос настроек сервера).

Да, в tomcat достаточно нарулить соответствующий коннектор. Для вашего же приложения это будет прозрачно. Ну и сертификаты купить/сгенерировать.

Comment: > По поводу не html.
В `response.getOutputStream` пишите все что душе угодно. И да, @avp прав, установите нужный заголовок.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на любую из реализаций веб-сервисов REST (стандарт JAX-RS). Это то, что вам нужно! Например, реализация Jersey (если используется GlassFish) или RESTeasy (если JBoss). Есть и куча других.